# OData connection using Lightining 2.0

Tags: lightning-connect, externalobjects

When i am set up the url in salesforce and validate ans sync i am receiving this error.
Please suggest me how to solve this ,its kind of urgency

> You don't have permission to view this external data. Update your
>   credentials, or contact your administrator for help with
>   authentication settings. Error received from the external system: 401

Comment: issue has been solved.it is the issue with credentials provided by external system.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved .we faced this error due to user access not provided on ODATA.
User which is using for odata set up similar user should be use in salesforce while set up the external data sources.